# Making a table that changes its row structure depending on what time it is

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a schedule table that would delete certain rows according to the current time.

Example;

(default table)

> 1st ride: 1.15
>
> 2nd ride: 1.45
>
> 3rd ride: 2.42

and let's say it is 1.16 so it changes into this;

(desired table)

> 2nd ride: 1.45
>
> 3rd ride: 2.42

How can I achieve this functionality?

Comment: Use some javascript or "dynamic language" (i.e. php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that with `HTML`.

However, you can do this either on *server side* (by a server-side script, like `PHP`, `ASP`, `perl`,  `python`, or whatever else you choose), or on *client side*, by `JavaScript`:

For example (here i'm using `Javascript` with [`jQuery` library](http://www.jquery.com) for convenience and shorter code):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    var now = new Date(); // create date object
    var h = now.getHours(); // get current hour
    var m = now.getMinutes(); // get current minute

    // if  the time is past 13:15 , hide first row of table with id 'mytable'
    if(h>13 || h>12 && m>15) {
       $('table#mytable tr:first').hide();
    } 
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank You!
Do You maybe have a tutorial on JavaScript tables to recommend as I am new to JS?

Comment: I don't have anything specific, but i'm sure if you google for 'javascript tables tutorial' there will be plenty of matches

Comment: @ValKalinic and read more about [`jQuery`](http://www.jquery.com) - it really makes life easier

Comment: Sorry to bother You, but I added this simple table
<table style="width: 300px;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="mytable">
  <tr>
    <td>13.10</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>13.25</td>
  </tr>
</table>
And it doesn't work, it does display it but nothing gets hidden. Do You know what the problem is?

Comment: @ValKalinic modified to hide first row (see live on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/poncha/6ACEX/) )

Comment: Thank You! Btw, I discovered it also works without h>13 as h>12 is enough